# Saving ManytoMany fields in Django with multiple forms

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do the following in 3 forms that are processed at once: 
1. Save the subject line for an email (this works)
2. Save the email content. (this works)
3. Save the email title (works) and save the relationship to the subject line and to the email content (not working).

I have read through every page I could which had to do with errors. I have tried it a variety of different ways, but they all haven't worked for me.

View.py:

```
def email_subject_create_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email_subject_form = EmailSubjectForm(request.POST)
        email_content_form = EmailContentForm(request.POST)
        email_form = EmailForm(request.POST)
        if email_subject_form.is_valid() and email_content_form.is_valid() and email_form.is_valid() :
            subject = email_subject_form.save(commit=False)
            subject.time_created = datetime.datetime.now()
            contractor = Contractor.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
            subject.save()
            email_subject_form.save_m2m()

            content = email_content_form.save(commit=False)
            content.time_created = datetime.datetime.now()
            content.save()
            email_content_form.save_m2m()

            email = email_form.save(commit=False)
            email.time_created = datetime.datetime.now()

            # this is what I want to do. email.email_core_contents is a M2M field
            email.email_subject_lines = subject.id


            email.save()

context = {
        'email_subject_form': EmailSubjectForm(),
        'email_content_form': EmailContentForm(),
        'email_form': EmailForm(),
}
return render(request, 'advertise/email_subject_create.html', context)
```

I have tried:

```
email.email_subject_lines = EmailSubject.objects.get(pk=subject.id)
email.email_subject_lines.set(subject)
email.email_subject_lines.set(pk=subject.id)
```

I have also tried it without the `.save_m2m()` portions of code.

Edit:

Error in the main example:

```
Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use email_subject_lines.set() instead.
```

Error in 1 of the 3 set:

```
Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use email_subject_lines.set() instead.
```

Error in the 2 of the 3 set:

```
"<Email: sfeaesfe>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Error in the 3 of the 3 set:

```
"<Email: graegre>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Comment: And exactly what happened when you tried those?

Comment: Error messages added.

Comment: OK. So what is unclear about errors 2 and 3?

Comment: I assume that means I need to call ```email.save()``` before that final expression to assign the m2m field. But I have tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Again, didn't work *how*? That is exactly the solution.

Comment: The error is: ```'EmailSubject' object is not iterable
``` when I put ```email.save()``` before ```email.email_subject_lines.set(subject)```.

Answer (score 0):

Found two solutions. Here they are in case anyone runs into the same problem in the future.

## 1: Use the add method.

```
email.email_subject_lines.add(subject)
email.email_core_contents.add(content)
```

## 2. Fetch both objects (Email and EmailSubject) from the database again.

```
email2 = Email.objects.get(id=email.id)
subject2 = EmailSubject.objects.filter(id=subject.id)
email2.email_subject_lines.set(subject2)
email2.save()
```

Not sure why it works this second way, but not the original way. Note that I had to use `filter` instead of `get` in the second expression.